# Javascript function taking too long to complete?

Tags: javascript

Below is a snipet of code that I am having trouble with. The purpose is to check duplicate entries in the database and return "h" with a boolean if true or false. For testing purposes I am returning a true boolean for "h" but by the time the alert(duplicate_count); line gets executed the duplicate_count is still 0. Even though the alert for a +1 gets executed.

To me it seems like the function updateUserFields is taking longer to execute so it's taking longer to finish before getting to the alert.

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks!

```
var duplicate_count = 0

for (var i = 0; i < skill_id.length; i++) {

    function updateUserFields(h) {
        if(h) {
            duplicate_count++;
            alert("count +1");
        } else {
            alert("none found");
        }
    }

    var g = new cfc_mentoring_find_mentor();
    g.setCallbackHandler(updateUserFields);
    g.is_relationship_duplicate(resource_id, mentee_id, section_id[i], skill_id[i], active_ind,table);
};

alert(duplicate_count);
```

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript for database logic?

Comment: I have Coldfusion handling the db queries, but the JQuery we use needs the fields returned from the queries.

Comment: If a loop is executing too long, it will trigger this browser alert. For such demanding loopss it's better to use timers, to avoid blocking the browsers main thread. It will take a bit longer with imers, but the main thread will be responsive...

Comment: You should look at using an ajax call, and when it returns, then you can make the decision whether to show the alert.  That way, if it takes 3 seconds or 30 seconds, your alert logic won't be executed until the server is done with the check.

Comment: Is .is_relationship_duplicate responsible for calling the callback? Its not clear to me. It doesnt seem this approach is even reasonable. You are firing a bunch of async calls then not waiting on them all to finish. And then trying to immediately read the results. You need some type of sync after the for loop

Comment: In your callback, increment a counter. Then after your for loop wait until the counter is equal to the number of loops you fired. Then you know they have finished.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no reason whatsoever** to use client-side JavaScript/jQuery to remove duplicates from your database.  Security concerns aside (and there are a lot of those), there is a much easier way to make sure the entries in your database are unique: use SQL.

SQL is capable of expressing the requirement that there be no duplicates in a table column, and the database engine will enforce that for you, never letting you insert a duplicate entry in the first place.  The syntax varies very slightly by database engine, but whenever you create the table you can specify that a column must be unique.

Let's use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) as our example database engine.  The relevant part of your problem is right now probably expressed with tables something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,
    -- Other fields here
);
CREATE TABLE MentorRelationship(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,
    mentorID INTEGER,
    menteeID INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (mentorID) REFERENCES Person(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (menteeID) REFERENCES Person(id)
);
```

However, you can make enforce uniqueness i.e. require that any `(mentorID, menteeID)` pair is unique, by changing the pair `(mentorID, menteeID)` to be the primary key.  This works because you are only allowed one copy of each primary key.  Then, the `MentorRelationship` table becomes

```
CREATE TABLE MentorRelationship(
    mentorID INTEGER,
    menteeID INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (mentorID, menteeID),
    FOREIGN KEY (mentorID) REFERENCES Person(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (menteeID) REFERENCES Person(id)
);
```

---

**EDIT**: As per the comment, alerting the user to duplicates but not actually removing them

This is still much better with SQL than with JavaScript.  When you do this in JavaScript, you read one database row at a time, send it over the network, wait for it to come to your page, process it, throw it away, and then request the next one.  With SQL, all the hard work is done by the database engine, and you don't lose time by transferring unnecessary data over the network.  Using the first set of table definitions above, you could write

```
SELECT mentorID, menteeID
FROM MentorRelationship
GROUP BY mentorID, menteeID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

which will return all the `(mentorID, menteeID)` pairs that occur more than once.

Once you have a query like this working on the server (and are also pulling out all the information you want to show to the user, which is presumably more than just a pair of IDs), you need to send this over the network to the user's web browser.  Essentially, on the server side you map a URL to return this information in some convenient form (JSON, XML, etc.), and on the client side you read this information by contacting that URL with an AJAX call (see [jQuery's website](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) for some code examples), and then display that information to the user.  No need to write in JavaScript what a database engine will execute orders of magnitude faster.

---

**EDIT 2**: As per the second comment, checking whether an item is already in the database

Almost everything I said in the first edit applies, except for two changes: the schema and the query.  The schema should become the second of the two schemas I posted, since you don't want the database engine to allow duplicates.  Also, the query should be simply

```
SELECT COUNT(*) > 0
FROM MentorRelationship
WHERE mentorID = @mentorID AND menteeID = @menteeID;
```

where `@mentorID` and `@menteeID` are the items that the user selected, and are inserted into the query by a query builder library and [not by string concatenation](http://xkcd.com/327/).  Then, the server will get a true value if the item is already in the database, and a false value otherwise.  The server can send that back to the client via AJAX as before, and the client (that's your JavaScript page) can alert the user if the item is already in the database.

Comment: I'm not removing duplicates, I need to give the user an alert if there are duplicates.

Comment: I agree with what you propose, you probably need a little more backround info to understand. I have a user that selects skills from a item list and prior to saving their skills I want to check the database to see if they already have entered these skills previously. If they did then I prompt them to make different choices. If not then saves them into the db. Hopefully that clarifies some ;)

Comment: @Brian "Understand" is a bit rich.  I understood what you wrote, but you wrote about checking for duplicates, not about checking whether an item already exists in the database *before* inserting it.  Nevertheless, I'm editing again to answer your clarified question.